# Why gradle application plugin fails to set JVM arguments

Tags: java, gradle, jvm-arguments

I have a Java program with a `main()` method which expects a system property `-Dmy_sys_prop=SOME_VALUE`. I use `application` plugin to execute my program. The configuration in my `build.gradle` looks like:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "application"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

ext.mySysProp = '"-Dmy_sys_prop=' + mySysProp + '"'

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [mySysProp]
mainClassName = "com.demo.SampleApp"

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}
```

I am using following command to run the program.

`./gradlew clean build run -PmySysProp=SOME_VALUE`

I am not able to understand why `mySysProp` value is not available to my Java program.

Could someone help me here? Or, show me a better way to achieve this.

Thanks,
NN

Comment: Have you tried to execute the program with the parameter but without gradle (e.g. from commandline)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes are off (this is not a shell environment where arguments can/need to be enclosed in quotes), and overriding `mySysProp` with an extra property of the same name is scary/confusing. Try:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-DmySysProp=$mySysProp"]
```

PS: I recommend to use `def foo = "bar"` instead of `ext.foo = "bar"` unless the property needs to be accessible from outer scopes and/or other build scripts (cf. local vs. global variable).